# SSH to server, Sudo su - then run commands in bash

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, sudo, aix

I have the following

```
#!/bin/bash

USER='scott'
PASS='tiger'

ssh -t $USER@server006.web.com "sudo su - http"
```

This Works, but I was trying to get it to run a script afterwards, and if I do, using -c or <

The script does a grep like this:

```
grep -i "Exception:" /opt/local/server/logs/exceptions.log | grep -e "|*-*-*:*:*,*|" | tail -1 | awk -F'|' '{print $2}' >> log.log
```

This also works fine on it's own, but I need to be http to do it.

I cannot SCP the output of the script back to server001 either, so I'm stuck here,

Any ideas would be relay appreciated. 
Ben

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
ssh -t $USER@server006.web.com 'sudo -u http grep -i "Exception:" /opt/local/server/logs/exceptions.log | grep -e "|*-*-*:*:*,*|" | tail -1 | awk -F"|" "{print $2}" >> log.log'
```

Sudo already runs the command as a different user to there's no need to su again.

Only reason to do sudo su is to have a fast way to start a new shell with another user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this and got ben@server006.server.com's password:
[sudo] password for ben:
Sorry, user benis not allowed to execute '/bin/grep -i Exception:...... as http on server006.server.com

Comment: Well the error pretty much says it all, the 'ben' user needs the proper permissions in /etc/sudoers. Usually be a member of the "sudo" or "admin" group.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want `sudo -u` instead of `sudo su -`:

```
ssh -t $USER@server006.web.com sudo -u http script
```

Comment: Tried this too man, I'm getting a connection closed error, saying user ben is not allowed to execute script.sh

Answer (score 3):

Guess I'm late to the party.
My solution:

```
ssh -t $USER@server006.web.com "sudo cat /etc/shadow"
```

and replace cat /etc/shadow with your desired program.